# How to hide a link from a screen-reader?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a link which I want to show to visitors with vision, but hide from visitors using screen-reader ATs. (This is not ideal of course).

This is the reverse of the usual problem (with known solution) of hiding content from vision visitors (e.g. a "skip to content" link)

An example:

[image: a box with lede text, and a link to "read more"]

Clicking the "read more" link expands the text inline.

[image: the same box, this time with all the text]

and conversely, clicking the "read less" link collapses it again.

This collapsed/expanding text functionality is only of benefit to visitors with vision, whose field of view would take in the extra text before they get to it (and in this example displaces the next FAQ, pushing it off screen).

A visitor with a screen-reader should instead be presented with the full text as they can choose to skip ahead to the next block, and they shouldn't encounter a spurious "read more" link which (a) doesn't link to a page, and (b) simply gives them what they were about to hear from their screen reader anyway.

How would this be done in HTML5?

Comment: `Screen-reader === blind user` is a simplistic assumption. Partially sighted users (and others) can also use a screen reader while still seeing what is on screen. Here it'd force them to hear text while not seeing it on screen (and being aware of that)

Comment: There are (almost) always exceptions ;-)

Comment: @FelipeAls do they use it to read the screen as a whole, or just selected parts? Do they use the screen-reader navigation functionality (eg. skip to next para/link/heading/section)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aria-hidden` this way for the content:

```
<p aria-hidden="true">Screen readers will not read this!</p>
```

Comment: Aria-hidden works great on plain text (as above), but can have some issues when used on links (or blocks containing links); screenreaders such as JAWS, NVDA and (desktop) VoiceOver will still allow a screenreader user to tab to the links, but will either remain silent as the user tabs, or in the case of JAWS, repeat the previous non-hidden link; either could be confusing. Taking the links out of tab order using tabindex=-1 isn't a good fix for this either, since then the links aren't usable by sighted keyboard users. I'm not sure there is a good solution here.

Comment: Perhaps the best solution for the most consistent and least confusing approach for all users would be to actually hide the hidden content from screen readers using aria-hidden="true" so all users would have to click the "read more" to keep reading.  This would keep the content as concise for screen readers users as it would for "visual" users and also keep the experience consistent for screen reader users with limited vision.  You wouldn't be able to use overflow:hidden, however, to hide the content and would instead need to hide based on elements which doesn't always give the same effect.

Comment: @ScruffyPaws Yep agreed, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the link in a pseudo element. That's brings another issue: you can't click on a pseudo element because is not part of the DOM, but can fake it with `pointer-events`.

```js
$("p").click(function () {
  $("span").toggleClass('on');
 });
```

```css
span {display:none; color:red}
p {pointer-events:none}
p:after {content:"Read more"; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; display: block;pointer-events:all}
span.on {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque at erat orci. Praesent non pulvinar nisl, at ultrices lorem. Sed semper ultricies eros, eu aliquet ipsum vehicula nec. Nullam orci justo, dapibus eget elit ac, tincidunt mollis urna. Ut sed felis lobortis, blandit urna non, fermentum arcu. Suspendisse fermentum elit ante. Nulla tincidunt elit vel elementum eleifend. Fusce sed nisi vulputate, aliquam urna congue, egestas arcu.<span> Praesent dignissim, risus in elementum eleifend, velit elit accumsan diam, sit amet vestibulum purus urna quis dui. Proin ut venenatis orci, sit amet ullamcorper tellus. Morbi lorem purus, ornare non convallis nec, venenatis cursus urna. Maecenas cursus, leo vel tincidunt viverra, leo nibh placerat sem, ut molestie tellus ex et nulla. Vivamus eget magna libero.</span></p>
```

I use `display:none`as an example, of course I assume you have your own method to hide the text but no for JAWS or other screen readers.